# Is the Parity Sudoku solvable?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

I have a new kind of grid puzzle (you could call it a variant of sudoku) I will be calling a Parity Sudoku.

Parity Sudoku is played on a 6x6 grid of integer cells with numbers ranging from 1 to 6. It has two main rules:

- For every cell with number k, every cell exactly k steps from it, either right, left, up or down has to have a different parity than it. (Oh, and since cells with number k=6 won't do anything with the rule above, their rule is changed so that they see cells exactly 5 steps from it right, left, up or down.)
- This grid also has one additional rule: Every number from 1 through 6 can occur only once in each 2x3 sextet of the grid - the location of the sextets is shown below.

```
***|***
***|***
-------
***|***
***|***
-------
***|***
***|***
```

- *The classic Latin square restriction is not necessary, but you could certainly include it. While it would make the rules more tight, it would be easier to find a contradiction that way.*

The main question is:

> **With the rules above, is the Parity Sudoku solvable?**

Bonus question: If we remove the sextet-rule, will it then be solvable?

Hint:

> Make a parity grid.

Comment: The same rules apply as a normal sudoku that every number should occur once in every column and row as well?

Comment: @Lezzup well, no. Safe to say, the rules are already very strict; there's no need to make them harsher ;)

Comment: In that case, glad I asked :)

Comment: I think that without the basic Latin square restriction, it's not really a sudoku variant. That doesn't mean it's not an interesting puzzle in its own right, though.

Comment: @fljx True... I was going to include the Latin square-restriction, but then it turned out that would be *way* too strict, so I eventually threw that away. What other names do you think I could change the name to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is rather cumbersome and I fully expect someone will make me look silly by posting a much simpler answer.*

First, we observe that a `1` placed on one of the two middle squares of a sextet will

> bind all even numbers available on that sextet including the `2`. If there is a neighbour of `1` opposite the `2` it cannot satisfy both parity constraints, therefore such a neighbour cannot exist. This rules out a `1` on these squares:

> ```
>     . . .  . . .
>     . x .  . x .
>
>     . x .  . x .
>     . x .  . x .
>
>     . x .  . x .
>     . . .  . . .
> ```

Now let's also rule out the remaining sextet middle positions:

Focusing on a stack of two sextets there is up to symmetry only one case

> ```
>     . x .       x O x       E O x
>     . x .       . x .       1 E .
>            ==>         ==>
>     . 2 .       . 2 .       E 2 .
>     E 1 E       E 1 E       E 1 E
> ```

Here `E` means (must be) even, `O` odd and `x` can't be `1`. We see that a `1` placed in the bottom middle position ultimately forces four even numbers on that sextet, contradiction.

Ruled out so far:

> ```
>     . x .  . x .
>     . x .  . x .
>
>     . x .  . x .
>     . x .  . x .
>
>     . x .  . x .
>     . x .  . x .
> ```

Next, we rule out the following configuration of two `1`s.

> ```
>     . x .       E x .
>     1 x .       1 E E
>            ==>
>     . x 1       E E 1
>     . x .       . x E
> ```

As not both `1`s can be hugging the boundary at most one of the `E`s can be a `2`, contradiction.

From this we can conclude that given a `1` in the corner of a sextet, the vertically adjacent sextet (if it exists) must have even numbers in two specific positions:

> ```
>     . . .       E . .       E . .
>     1 . .       1 E .       1 E .
>            ==>         ==>
>
>     x x x       E x x       E . .
>     . x .       . E .       1 E .
> ```

Furthermore, none of the four indicated `E`s can be a `2`.

We also observe that of the two candidate positions for the second `1` only the left one is viable, because the top neighbour of the right one cannot be  a `2` but no other evens are left.

And, finally, we remark that a three-storey version of this configuration is not possible because some of the `E`s have to be `4`s.

Next we zoom in on the two middle sextets:

This configuration is impossible

> ```
>     . x .  . x .
>     1 x .  1 x .
>
>          ||
>          \/
>
>     E x .  E x .
>     1 E E  1 E .
> ```

because none of the three indicated `E`s in the left sextet can be a `2`.
Please note that this argument also holds for the bottom row of sextets if the middle left sextet has its `1` in its lower half.

> ```
>     . x .  . x .
>     1 x .  . x 1
>
>          ||
>          \/
>
>     4 x .  . x 4
>     1 6 .  . 6 1
> ```

In this configuration of `1`s the indicated `4`s are `4`s because they cannot be `2`s or `6`s, leaving for the other non-`2`s only `6`s. But now none of the remaining squares can be a `2`, contradiction.

What we know so far:

Both the left and the right halves must have `1`s in the top and bottom rows; the respective third `1`s cannot be on the same row. Also they must be in the same column as the closer one of the bottom or top row `1`s.

Furthermore, the ones farther away can only be at the very corner.

This rules out that the closer ones are in the corner because

> ```
>     1 E .  . . 1
>     E . .  . . E
>
>     1 . .  . . .
>     . . .  . . 1
>
>     . . .  . . .
>     1 E .  . . 1
> ```

we remember that one of the two top left `E`s has to be a `6`.

But they cannot be in the centre either

> ```
>     . . 1  . E 1
>     . . .  . . E
>
>     . E 1  E . .
>     . . E  1 . .
>
>     . . .  . . .
>     1 . .  1 . .
> ```

because there cannot be a `2` in the middle right sextet.

So the answer is

> No, it is not solvable.

Comment: Doesn't your conclusion follow immediately from your fourth spoiler-block and the fact that every column must contain the digit you mention?

Comment: @RosieF there is no Latin square constraint. (See comments on the question.)

Comment: Great work! I was hoping for something more elegant, but the proof is definitely correct.